# Listen for deletion of input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, input, listener

One of the most recommended ways to listen for a change of a input text field is to bind that field to a key up event. That works fine in most cases. But there are cases where this is not working. In Firefox for example one has the option, when text is already selected, to delete it by using the context menu. And this doesn't fire a key up event. I haven't found any event that is fired for that text field when doing this.
Any suggestions how I can react on this (in pure Javascript or jQuery)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the `oninput` event, and my write up about it [here](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript).

`oninput` fires for all forms of text input - including cut, paste, undo, redo, clear, drag and drop and spelling corrections.  It's a HTML 5 event which isn't supported in Internet Explorer 8 and lower (but it is in the latest IE 9 preview).  However, Internet Explorer supports a proprietary event on all DOM objects - `onpropertychange`.  This fires whenever the value of an input element changes.

I didn't notice you'd tagged with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) — since you did, it's probably worth mentioning that I wrote a plugin to implement the `oninput` event cross browser.  You can find it [here](http://whattheheadsaid.com/projects/input-special-event).

Comment: You've got this issue sewn up, I think.

Comment: @Tim: haha, I'm certainly trying :-)

Comment: @Tim: Other than the bugs he mentions in his blog post, yeah.

Comment: @TJC even with those bugs, `oninput` is *still* better than key events.  I noticed yesterday that Opera 11 alpha fixes those issues.

Comment: Andy, one problem with your implementation (at least with Firefox 3.6.12 under Linux). The sites on which an input is bound to the input event are initially automatically scrolled to the end. Yes, I know ... it sounds weird, but I checked it multiple times under several conditions. I also tried to debug it. It happens somewhere inside jQuery, soon after the inputt binding was attached ... during the initialization.

Comment: @Zardoz: hmm... that could be because of the specific workaround required to detect `oninput` event support in Firefox.  [This bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195696) details that issue.  I'll have a look into it today if I get time.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Could you update me here if you find a workaround. That would be great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store the value on a `focus` event and recheck the value on a `blur` event. Listening to key events fires a lot of usually redundant processes. Most of the time, you are only interrested in a field value when the user is done inputting (or deleting) it.

This works cross browser, though delegating focus/blur can be an issue in some browsers. The easiest way is to apply blur/focus listeners to the element directly.

Only exceptions are implementations like autosuggest/complete and even then you might want to debounce key input so it only fires when the user idles for a few hundred miliseconds.